# Can't connect to my Derby database

Tags: java, jdbc, derby

I created a new database using Java DB named "Test", and I tried to create a connection using java DB Embedded driver, but when I enter Test in database name and add user name and pass and press OK, an error appears:

> "Unable to add connection. cannot establish a connection to jdbc.derby.Test using org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver (database 'Test' not found)"

Why do I get this message?

then, when I wrote my code

```
   String conStr = "jdbc:derby:Test";
    String driver2 = "org.apache.derby.jdbc.EmbeddedDriver";
    try {
        Class.forName(driver2);
        System.out.println("driver");
    } catch (ClassNotFoundException e1) {
        e1.printStackTrace();
    }
    try {
        Properties props = new Properties();
        props.put("user", "sahar");
        props.put("password", "123456"); 
        //Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr);
        Connection conn = DriverManager.getConnection(conStr,props);
        System.out.println("connect ");
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

it throws an exception "Database 'Test' not found"

Comment: Try to gather more information by following these instructions: http://wiki.apache.org/db-derby/UnwindExceptionChain

Answer (score 3):

If indeed you have created a local database, try pointing to the absolute file-name instead of the relative one.

```
Unix:
jdbc:derby:/srv/databases/Test

Windows:
jdbc:derby:c:/databases/Test
```

Better way might be to access a database via a Derby network server

Comment: but this is the absolute path
C:\Users\m\.netbeans-derby\Test. but it throws an exception "Failed to start database 'c:\Users\m\.netbeans-derby\Test' "

Comment: Watch out for backslashes. In Java, you probably have to double the backslashes.

Comment: @BryanPendleton, I use jdbc:derby:c:\\Users\\m\\.netbeans-derby\\Test
but it throws an exception "Failed to start database 'c:\Users\m\.netbeans-derby\Test' " why?

Comment: blackslashes work only if you call derby from command line, in code you must use forward slashes try something like: getConnection("jdbc:derby://localhost/c:/Users/m/.netbeans-derby/Test")

Comment: @Hypnos
a new exception is thrown
java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:derby://localhost/c:/Users/m/.netbeans-derby/Test

Comment: @sasola either the derbyclient.jar is missing from the classpath or the database cannot be reached. Adding ;create=true to the end of the jdbc address with ensure that the database exists (otherwise it will be created).

Comment: @Hypnos, I added derbyClient.jar to the project and the code runs successfully, but I know that I use derbyClient.jar when I user ClientDriver not Embedded driver! why I should add derbyClient.jar ?

Answer (score 1):

Without seeing code it's hard to guess, but perhaps you need `create=true` on your connection string.

```
final String connectionURL = "jdbc:derby:" + dbName + ";create=true";
```

(I pulled this copy and paste out of an app I have that uses an embedded database.)

Comment: but i don't want to create the database it is already exist
and I don't talk about any code, I make that using netbeans wizard

Comment: and when I write my code to connect to this database it throws and exception Database "Test" not found

Comment: Well then, you need to change your working directory. Check your working directory against the physical directory of the database.

Comment: but it is in the default directory , how to change the directory?

Comment: C:\Users\m\.netbeans-derby
this where Test database exists

Comment: I would try `String conStr = "jdbc:derby:c:\\Users\\m\\.netbeans-derby\\Test";` to see if that works for you. The syntax on that might be wrong, so you may need to look up exactly how to point directly to a filename.

Comment: it throws a new exception 
SQL Exception: Failed to start database 'c:\Users\m\.netbeans-derby\Test', see the next exception for details.